# Ruby LoadError with gmp

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gmp

```
$ gem install gmp
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed gmp-0.7.43
Parsing documentation for gmp-0.7.43
Done installing documentation for gmp after 0 seconds
1 gem installed


$ cat gmp-test.rb
require 'gmp'

$ /opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/bin/ruby gmp-test.rb
<internal:/opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/dunham/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/gmp-0.7.43/lib/../ext/gmp (LoadError)
    from <internal:/opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /home/dunham/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/gmp-0.7.43/lib/gmp.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:159:in `require'
    from <internal:/opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:159:in `rescue in require'
    from <internal:/opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:149:in `require'
    from gmp-test.rb:1:in `<main>'
<internal:/opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- gmp (LoadError)
    from <internal:/opt/src/ruby-3.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from gmp-test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: FWIW I get the same error on macOS with Ruby 3.2.0.

Comment: The error message is unexpected. But at the same time, I am not surprised that a gem that got it last update about 6 years ago, is not playing well with Ruby 3.2. According to the gem's commit history, I guess it only supports Ruby 2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library seems to be dead. It's expecting `gmp.so` to be in `ext` directory but it ends up in `lib` directory, it's probably new `rubygems` doing things differently.

```rb
>> require "gmp"
<internal:/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in 'require': 
cannot load such file -- /home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/gmp-0.7.43/lib/../ext/gmp (LoadError)
```

```bash
$ ls $(dirname $(gem which gmp))
gmp.rb  gmp.so
#  move ^ that to ../ext/

$ mv $(dirname $(gem which gmp))/gmp.so $(dirname $(gem which gmp))/../ext/
```

```rb
>> require "gmp"
=> true
>> GMP::Z(0)
=> 0
```

---

**Update**

From the linked logs looks like you're still not loading `gmp.so` which is where all the classes are defined. You can copy `gmp.so` into your app:

```bash
# copy `gmp.rb`
$ cp $(gem which gmp) .
# copy `gmp.so`
$ cp $(dirname $(gem which gmp))/gmp.so .
# or if you moved it to ext
$ cp $(dirname $(gem which gmp))/../ext/gmp.so .
```

```bash
$ touch app.rb
$ ls
app.rb  gmp.rb  gmp.so
```

*gmp.rb* defines `GMP.sprintf` method, if this is not a required method and you don't use it, you can remove this file.

```rb
# gmp.rb

# require 'rbconfig'
#
# ENV['PATH'] = [File.expand_path(
#   File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "ext")
# ), ENV['PATH']].compact.join(';') if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /(mswin|mingw|mingw32)/i
#
# require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../ext/gmp'

# unless RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1.8/
  module GMP
    def self.sprintf(format, *args)
      first_pct = format.index '%'
      result = format[0...first_pct]
      #format.gsub(/(?<!%)%[0#+ ']*[0-9]*.?[0-9]*[a-zA-Z][^%]*/) do |fragment|
      format.gsub(Regexp.new('(?<!%)%[0#+ \']*[0-9]*.?[0-9]*[a-zA-Z][^%]*')) do |fragment|
        arg = args.shift
        if fragment =~ /%[0#+ ']*[0-9]*.?[0-9]*[ZQF]/
          result << sprintf2(fragment, arg)
        elsif fragment =~ /%[0#+ ']*[0-9]*.?[0-9]*[PR]/ && GMP.const_defined?(:MPFR_VERSION)
          result << GMP::F.sprintf2(fragment, arg)
        else
          result << (fragment % arg)
        end
      end
      result
    end
  end
# end
```

```rb
# app.rb

require_relative "gmp.so"
p GMP::Z
p GMP::Z(0)
p GMP::Q
p GMP::F

require_relative "gmp.rb"
p GMP.sprintf "%Zd", GMP.Z(0)
```

```bash
$ ruby --yjit -v
ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) +YJIT [x86_64-linux]
$ ruby --yjit app.rb
GMP::Z
0
GMP::Q
GMP::F
"0"
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a really helpful answer. I'd started to realize that I could try moving things into that folder, but it would have taken a lot more for me to figure it out. Unfortunately I reached some more problems with the actual programs I was trying to fix https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/pidigits-ruby-2.html#log and https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/pidigits-ruby-5.html#log

Comment: @igouy see update. i've also tried your code, works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for following through. With require_relative I am able to get those programs to work in this limited context. Of course it would be better for me to understand why I've been having so much difficulty with ruby paths, but at least this small task is done.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I now have gmp working with old MRI and YJIT see pidigits programs here https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/ruby.html